# Showing git tag message

Tags: git, tags

So,

If I do this:

```
 git tag -a v4.2 -m 'my message'
```

And then I run:

```
git show v4.2
```

Insead of seeing 'my message', I see the message of the last commit.

How can I see the message of that tag?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print the message of a git tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561789/print-the-message-of-a-git-tag)

Answer (score 12):

From the [`git show` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html):

> For tags, it shows the tag message and the referenced objects.

So what you've described should work fine.  Here's a complete example:

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/carl/Desktop/example/.git/
$ touch file
$ git add file
$ git commit -m "added a file"
[master (root-commit) 198fa55] added a file
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file
$ git tag -a sometag -m "tag message"
$ git show sometag
tag sometag
Tagger: Carl Norum <somebody@somewhere>
Date:   Mon Jul 8 10:10:49 2013 -0700

tag message

commit 198fa55868770ab78786e704dbb290cbeefac011
Author: Carl Norum <somebody@somewhere>
Date:   Mon Jul 8 10:10:42 2013 -0700

    added a file

diff --git a/file b/file
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the -n option with either 'git -l' or 'git tag'.  This will show all tags with (the first line of) their messages:

```
git tag -n
```

-n takes an optional number of lines of the annotation to display, it defaults to one.  From the [git tag reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag):

> -n<num>
>
> ```
> <num> specifies how many lines from the annotation, if any, are printed when using -l. Implies --list.
>
> The default is not to print any annotation lines. If no number is given to -n, only the first line is printed. If the tag is not annotated, the commit message is displayed instead.
> ```

Comment: yes, using `git tag` is the way to go, see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48693527/529977