# Print the message of a git tag

Tags: git, git-tag

I need a git command that would output only the message of a given annotated tag. It's *almost* possible with `git tag -ln`:

```
$ git tag -ln v1.3.7
v1.3.7          Here be annotations
```

It's just that I don't want the tag and whitespace in the beginning, and throwing a regex at this feels like overkill. Is there any built-in flag i could use? I'm using git version 1.8.3.2.

Some of the answers at [Print commit message of a given commit in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3357280/454094) use `git show --format=%B`. I can't seem to restrict output to only the message, neither for commits or tags.

Comment: The answer does not necessarily need to use the format flag, if a different solution exists.

Comment: The question you linked to is quite different. It asks for _a list of all tags_ (with message included). I'm asking for _a single tag_, and with all details except the message omitted.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'm not sure what version of git this requires, but with recent versions you can also do:

```
git tag -l --format='%(contents)' <tag name>
```

or

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(contents)' refs/tags/<tag name>
```

to get only the tag message by itself, where latter one is some like the base command without `--sort=-version:refname`.

Comment: Note that if the tag is not annotated, this prints the commit message.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the PGP signature?

Comment: @SOFe `git tag -l --format='%(contents:subject)'` returns only the first line of the message.

Answer (score 6):

I got just the message (but the message included some extraneous stuff like PGP signature and signed-off-by lines) when I said:

```
git show -s --format=%B <tag>
```

Note the `-s`.

Comment: Yes, I'd have expected this to do what I want. The extra stuff is in the way though. You'd think since `git tag -ln` excludes it, it would be possible to leave out from `show` as well.