# Can I sign a git tag after it was created?

Tags: git, sign

I created a tag and forgot to sign it, then pushed the tag to GitHub. Is it possible to just sign that tag retroactively, or do I have to create a new tag?

I have read the man page for `git tag` and googled a bit, but have come up with no clues that adding a signature to an already existing tag is possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No you would need to::

- [replace it with a tag using the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7813236/6309):

  ```
    git tag <tag name> <tag name> -f -s
  ```
- but first set the committer date, in order to not change the date

  ```
    set GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="$(git log -1 --format=%aD <tag_name>)"
  ```

As [mrts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258772/mrts) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347534/can-i-sign-a-git-tag-after-it-was-created/25347576?noredirect=1#comment120641616_25347576), since the tag was already pushed:

> You also need to **force push** the *updated* tag with `git push origin <tag_name> -f`

---

Starting with Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), you can sign only the tags which need it, using:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname) %(signature)' refs/tags | python re-sign-tags.py
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                   (new with Git 2.42)
```

And `re-sign-tags.py`

```py
import sys
import subprocess

def verify_tag(refname, signature):
    grade = signature.split(":")[1]
    if grade == "good":
        print("Tag '%s' is signed with a good signature." % refname)
    else:
        print("Tag '%s' is signed with a bad signature." % refname)

def re_sign_tag(refname, signature):
    signer = signature.split(":")[1]
    print("Re-signing tag '%s' with key '%s'." % (refname, signer))
    subprocess.run(["git", "tag", "-f", refname, refname, "-s"], check=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for refname, signature in sys.stdin:
        if refname.startswith("refs/tags/"):
            if verify_tag(refname, signature):
                re_sign_tag(refname, signature)
```

---

With Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), the "[`git for-each-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/81ebc54e81619ccc71fca6a4ce7822e78b24e80c/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref))</sup> family of commands learned placeholders related to GPG signature verification.

See [commit 26c9c03](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26c9c03f0a9c26f5e41af19f3cbd6f4dda7006b3), [commit 2f36339](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f36339fa8622ee1cba957e8d0ef15719c697de3) (04 Jun 2023) by [Kousik Sanagavarapu (`five-sh`)](https://github.com/five-sh).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 81ebc54](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81ebc54e81619ccc71fca6a4ce7822e78b24e80c), 14 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`ref-filter`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26c9c03f0a9c26f5e41af19f3cbd6f4dda7006b3): add new "signature" atom
>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Hariom Verma</sup>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Jaydeep Das</sup>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Nsengiyumva Wilberforce</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Christian Couder</sup>
> <sup>Mentored-by: Hariom Verma</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kousik Sanagavarapu</sup>

> Duplicate the code for outputting the signature and its other parameters for commits and tags in ref-filter from pretty.
> In the future, this will help in getting rid of the current duplicate implementations of such logic everywhere, when ref-filter can do everything that pretty is doing.
>
> The new atom "signature" and its friends are equivalent to the existing pretty formats as follows:
>
> ```
> %(signature) = %GG
> %(signature:grade) = %G?
> %(siganture:signer) = %GS
> %(signature:key) = %GK
> %(signature:fingerprint) = %GF
> %(signature:primarykeyfingerprint) = %GP
> %(signature:trustlevel) = %GT
> ```

`git for-each-ref` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/26c9c03f0a9c26f5e41af19f3cbd6f4dda7006b3/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt#L224-L250):

> ### `signature`
>
> The GPG signature of a commit.
>
> ### `signature:grade`
>
> Show "G" for a good (valid) signature, "B" for a bad
> signature, "U" for a good signature with unknown validity, "X"
> for a good signature that has expired, "Y" for a good
> signature made by an expired key, "R" for a good signature
> made by a revoked key, "E" if the signature cannot be
> checked (e.g. missing key) and "N" for no signature.
>
> ### `signature:signer`
>
> The signer of the GPG signature of a commit.
>
> ### `signature:key`
>
> The key of the GPG signature of a commit.
>
> ### `signature:fingerprint`
>
> The fingerprint of the GPG signature of a commit.
>
> ### `signature:primarykeyfingerprint`
>
> The primary key fingerprint of the GPG signature of a commit.
>
> ### `signature:trustlevel`
>
> The trust level of the GPG signature of a commit. Possible
> outputs are `ultimate`, `fully`, `marginal`, `never` and `undefined`.

Comment: See also, on a similar topic (including the push): http://stackoverflow.com/a/21741848/6309

Comment: You also need to force push the updated tag with `git push origin <tag_name> -f`.

Comment: @mrts Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but going off of what [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) said. I created a one-line bash script that can go through all of your tags in your repository and sign them automatically. All you have to do is either accept or change the message set in the old tag. Here is the command I came up with

```sh
git for-each-ref refs/tags | awk '{print $3}' | cut -c11- | xargs -I % sh -c 'git tag % % -f -s'
```