# Command to remove GitHub Draft release

Tags: git, github, github-api, git-tag

I'm trying to delete a Release in GitHub, so I'm doing

```
git tag -d {release-tag-name}
git push origin :{release-tag-name}
```

This removes the tag (local and remote) but it leaves a `Draft` release in GitHub that I also want to delete.

I can delete it by login into GitHub and clicking the delete button but I want to avoid doing this through the website.

Is there a command to achieve this? I've found some other similar postings about removing tags but they all end up going to GitHub to delete the `Draft`.

**Edit**

In this [question's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738647/change-date-of-git-tag-or-github-release-based-on-it) Step 2 and 5 are related to my question. Step 2 says `This will turn your "Release" on GitHub into a Draft that you can later delete.` while step 5 instructs to delete the Draft in GitHub's site, not trough a command.

Comment: Maybe I am not reading it right. You want to know how to delete a remote branch?

Comment: I updated my question, I hope it's clearer

Comment: possible douplicate of [how-to-delete-a-remote-tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480258/how-to-delete-a-remote-tag)

Comment: @marcusshep that question removes the tag but I need to remove the Draft version that's left in GitHub after removing the tag

Comment: What is a draft version

Comment: @marcusshep I think it is a remote branch that isn't a tagged release. @jorgehmv does `git push :<remote_branch_name> delete that 'draft version'? Warning: this will delete the branch.

Comment: is it 5 o' clock yet

Comment: @BryceDrew It won't delete it

Comment: Someone worked on this feature for `hub` command line: https://github.com/github/hub/issues/1326 It's not merged right now, but maybe it works

On github, a draft version _can be_ a release that was created but its tag was then removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Releases are not something git CLI can help you with.

Releases are GitHub specific thing.

You can use [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#delete-a-release) to create/update/delete releases.

```
DELETE /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:id
```

If you want to automate interaction with GitHub API you can do the following:

1. [Get an API token](https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens) with proper permissions.
2. Store it somewhere, let's say environment variables.
3. Write a few scripts.

For example in this case you can have one script to  delete local tag, call API to get tag id [by name](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#get-a-release-by-tag-name), delete remote tag and delete a release.

Answer (score 9):

Since @GabLeRoux pointed out that `hub` now includes the ability to delete releases, and it has the ability to list drafts and format the output as we wish, I wrote the following to delete all draft releases from our repo:

`hub release -f "%T (%S) %n" --include-drafts | grep " (draft)" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -t -n1 hub release delete`

Breaking this down:

`hub release -f "%T (%S) %n" --include-drafts`: Prints all releases, and if they have a status like "draft" or "pre-release", put that status inside of parenthesis. You'll end up with output like this:

```
release-name-1 ()
release-name-2 ()
release-name-3 (draft)
release-name-4 ()
release-name-5 (draft)
release-name-6
```

Now pipe that into `| grep " (draft)"` so that we only print lines with `(draft)`:

```
release-name-3 (draft)
release-name-5 (draft)
```

Now for each of those lines, pipe that into `| awk '{print $1}'` to take only the first part (before the first space). (This won't work if any releases have spaces in their name):

```
release-name-3
release-name-5
```

Now pipe all of those draft release names into `xargs -t -n1 hub release delete`, which will call `hub release delete <RELEASE_NAME_HERE>` for each line of input:

```
hub release delete release-name-3
hub release delete release-name-5
```

(As for those xargs params: `-t` echoes the command first, and `-n1` tells it to make a separate call to `hub` for every line of input.)

If you want to go slow and see what draft releases it thinks it should delete, just run this portion:

`hub release -f "%T (%S) %n" --include-drafts | grep " (draft)" | awk '{print $1}'`

And if you want to go really slow, add `-p` as a param to xargs, and it will prompt you before running each command.

Comment: Almost worked, for some reason when i run it, the "Draft" card's were still appearing, I deleted all tag with `git tag -d tagname` and then `git push origin :refs/tags/tagname` one by one and after running that command, most of them were gone just couple missing.

Comment: Good answer, I've just realized that with this method, you won't be able to delete untagged releases. Those can be releaes, which lost it's tags after doing a `tag -d tagname`

Comment: This should be the Answer.  It works for me.  You can use homebrew (mac) or choco (Windows) to install hub cli. https://hub.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this too. Anton Sizikov's answer is right but working with github's api directly may be a bit tricky sometimes.

**[hub](https://github.com/github/hub)** had [an issue on this](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/1326), and the [PR is now merged](https://github.com/github/hub/pull/1327)

To delete a release, all you need to do is [install `hub`](https://hub.github.com/) and run this inside your project's folder:

```bash
hub release delete <TAG>
```

You can delete all the releases with something like this

```bash
git fetch --all --tags
git tag | xargs hub release delete
```

Or you can list all the tags you want to delete in a file (one tag per line), then do this:

```bash
cat tags_i_want_to_delete.txt | xargs hub release delete
```

See [tldr `xargs` for details](https://github.com/tldr-pages/tldr/blob/master/pages/common/xargs.md)

### Alternative solution: working nodejs example to remove draft tags

Thanks to Steve Mao for [github-remove-all-releases](https://github.com/stevemao/github-remove-all-releases)!

```sh
npm init
npm install --save github-remove-all-releases dotenv
```

`main.js`:

```js
require('dotenv').config();

var githubRemoveAllReleases = require('github-remove-all-releases');

var AUTH = {
    type: 'oauth',
    token: process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN
};

// this is where the magic happens, we filter on tag.draft, if it's true, it will get deleted
a_filter = function (tag) {
    return Boolean(tag.draft);
};

a_callback = function (result) {
    console.log (result);
};

githubRemoveAllReleases(AUTH, process.env.GITHUB_OWNER, process.env.GITHUB_REPO, a_callback, a_filter);
```

[Get yourself a token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) and create a `.env` file like this:

```sh
GITHUB_OWNER=owner
GITHUB_REPO=repo
GITHUB_TOKEN=your_token
```

Then run this (a few times as it does not support pagination):

```sh
npm main.js
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. People need to be aware that the only output you get is "null" without telling you it did delete something.

Comment: Good point, I suppose it's possible to fork `github-remove-all-releases`, edit its `index.js` by adding some `console.log` or even adding some more code in my snippet in the `a_filter ` function, something like `if (Boolean(tag.draft)) { console.log(tag + "will be deleted"); return true; } else { return false; }` (untested, but you get the idea). ;)

Comment: I wish people down-voting could write why they did so. I'm wondering what went wrong as this totally worked on my side. Plus, `hub`'s [pull request is now merged](https://github.com/github/hub/pull/1327) so one can simply execute `hub release delete <TAG>`. Updating answer accordingly :)