# Change versioning scheme of old git tags

Tags: git, version, git-tag

I want to rename all old tags to match the changed versioning scheme, along with amending tagged commits and they're messages. The important thing is to preserve the date of each tag and its commit. Is this possible, and how? I found solutions to do this, but all of them change the date. Note that team conflicts, caused by the changes, are not an issue.

Comment: Probably you want to re-write you tags while setting `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#_on_backdating_tags

Comment: Conflicts among team members aren't the only reason to avoid rewriting commits. This is a major undertaking. Please make sure that the tradeoff is worth it.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21741848/7976758