# Using GitHub API to update a Release date

Tags: github, release, github-api

I would like to update the date (timestamp) of an existing GitHub Release.

Currently, I'm using the [Git Database > References > Update a reference](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#update-a-reference) API to update the tag `SHA`. Unfortunately, that API does not accept `timestamp` or `date`, and I'm not even sure if it's relevant since it's a tag and not a Release.

I also went through [Repositories > Releases > Update a release](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#releases) API, and still no luck.

The only solution I can think of is deleting the release and recreating it, which is really something that I want to avoid. Any help with solving this challenge is appreciated.

**Note**: I saw this question [Change date of git tag (or GitHub Release based on it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738647/change-date-of-git-tag-or-github-release-based-on-it), but the offered solutions are implemented with `git` CLI and it's not what I'm looking for.