# Github Action prints Commit Message instead of Tag Message

Tags: git, github-actions

I want to print the current git Tag's **message** in a Github Action.

If I run the following locally:

```
git tag -l --sort=-taggerdate --format='%(contents)' $(git describe --tags $(git branch --show-current) )
```

It prints the tag msg:

```
v1.1.1-155

* Bug fixes
```

However when running the Github Action, it prints the latest commit's message.

**How can I make Github Actions print the tag and not the commit?**

---

The build.yml trigger for the Action is:

```
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'
```

Comment: Do you want only the latest tag to be printed? If yes, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rponte/fdc0724dd984088606b0) could maybe help you get what you want.

Comment: @GuiFalourd The gist only prints the tag, and not the annotaded tag message.

Comment: In that case, would [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561789/print-the-message-of-a-git-tag) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to fetch all tags apparently:

```
- name: Fetch Tags
  run: git fetch --tags --force
```